# Increment counters of node and ALL parents using firebase realtime db cloud functions

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I'm writing cloud functions for my firebase realtime database (not firestore) using js sdk. These functions increment counters that count the number of users per area. The areas I'm using are geographical and nested (Continent>Country>Region>City). The functions are triggered by the insertion of a user into the users list of a given area (.onCreate). If a user is inserted into the users list of let's say a country, it will automatically be added to the users list of the parent continent.

After tinkering for some time I was only able to come up with a "low-level" non-scalable solution (which by the way works). This means that I need to write additionnal code if I want to add a child area to city for example.

This is a problem because I expect to add child areas in the future.

Question: Is there a way to write a generic cloud function that increments the counters of a node and the counters of all its parent nodes?

I'm quite new to firebase and any help would be really appreciated

## Json structure of firebase realtime db

```
{
  "groups" : {
    "location" : {
      "continents" : {
        "EU" : {
          "countries" : {
            "DE" : {
              "created" : "2019-03-25--20:03:34",
              "flag" : "/flags/de.svg",
              "label" : "Germany",
              "level" : 2,
              "regions" : {
                "BE" : {
                  "cities" : {
                    "Berlin" : {
                      "created" : "2019-03-25--20:03:35",
                      "label" : "Berlin",
                      "level" : 3,
                      "type" : "location",
                      "usercount" : 1,
                      "users" : {
                        "rvDUa5n0oufRFGA9JB7lioom0ac2" : {
                          "created" : "2019-03-25--20:03:55",
                          "label" : "Anonymous"
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  "created" : "2019-03-25--20:03:35",
                  "label" : "Land Berlin",
                  "level" : 3,
                  "type" : "location",
                  "usercount" : 1,
                  "users" : {
                    "rvDUa5n0oufRFGA9JB7lioom0ac2" : {
                      "created" : "2019-03-25--20:03:52",
                      "label" : "Anonymous"
                    }
                  }
                }
              },
              "type" : "location",
              "usercount" : 1,
              "users" : {
                "rvDUa5n0oufRFGA9JB7lioom0ac2" : {
                  "created" : "2019-03-25--20:03:49",
                  "label" : "Anonymous"
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "created" : "2019-03-25--20:03:33",
          "label" : "Europe",
          "level" : 1,
          "type" : "location",
          "usercount" : 1,
          "users" : {
            "rvDUa5n0oufRFGA9JB7lioom0ac2" : {
              "created" : "2019-03-25--20:03:46",
              "label" : "Anonymous"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

## My cloud functions for user insertion - still need to write for user deletion

```
exports.onUserAddToContinent = functions.database
.ref('/groups/location/continents/{continentID}/users/{userID}')
.onCreate((snapshot, context) => {

const continentId = context.params.continentID
const counterRef = admin.database().ref('/groups/location/continents/' + continentId + '/usercount');

return counterRef.transaction(usercount => {
  return (usercount || 0) + 1
  })
})

exports.onUserAddToCountry = functions.database
.ref('/groups/location/continents/{continentID}/countries/{countryID}/users/{userID}')
.onCreate((snapshot, context) => {

    const continentId = context.params.continentID
    const countryId = context.params.countryID
    const counterRef = admin.database().ref('/groups/location/continents/' + continentId + '/countries/' + countryId + '/usercount');

    return counterRef.transaction(usercount => {
      return (usercount || 0) + 1
      })
})

exports.onUserAddToRegion = functions.database
.ref('/groups/location/continents/{continentID}/countries/{countryID}/regions/{regionID}/users/{userID}')
.onCreate((snapshot, context) => {

    const continentId = context.params.continentID
    const countryId = context.params.countryID
    const regionId = context.params.regionID
    const counterRef = admin.database().ref('/groups/location/continents/' + continentId + '/countries/' + countryId + '/regions/' + regionId +'/usercount');

    return counterRef.transaction(usercount => {
      return (usercount || 0) + 1
      })
})

exports.onUserAddToCity = functions.database
.ref('/groups/location/continents/{continentID}/countries/{countryID}/regions/{regionID}/cities/{cityID}/users/{userID}')
.onCreate((snapshot, context) => {

    const continentId = context.params.continentID
    const countryId = context.params.countryID
    const regionId = context.params.regionID
    const cityId = context.params.cityID
    const counterRef = admin.database().ref('/groups/location/continents/' + continentId + '/countries/' + countryId + '/regions/' + regionId +'/cities/'+ cityId + '/usercount');

    return counterRef.transaction(usercount => {
      return (usercount || 0) + 1
      })
})
```

I feel 'im missing something. There has to be a generic way of doing this.